# Get notification of HttpWebResponse

Tags: windows-phone-8, httpwebrequest, asynccallback

I have a ComClass for windows phone 8 that post and read data from a url.

```
 public class ComClass
    {
        private string _url = """;
        private  string _postdata = "";
        public Boolean data_received;
        public string data;

        public  ComClass(string url, string data2send)
        {
            _url = url;
            _postdata = data2send;
        }    

        public void Send()
        {
            data_received = false;
            HttpWebRequest request = null;           

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            request.Method = "POST";

            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
        }

        private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;            
            Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_postdata.ToString());

            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, _postdata.Length);
            postStream.Dispose();

           request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
        }

        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                data = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

                data_received = true;

                streamResponse.Dispose();
                streamRead.Dispose();                
                response.Dispose();
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                data = ex.Message;
                data_received = false;
                //using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                //{
                //    //Debug.WriteLine("Exception output : " + ex);
                //}
            }
        }
    }
```

The class works fine. My problem is that i want somehow to get notified that i have a response. eg

```
ComClass ccc = null;
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                ccc = new ComClass("url", "somedata");

                ccc.Send();

                //while (ccc.data_received == false)
                //{ }

                 string itemdata = ccc.data;
                 //do something with itemdata...
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            { 

            }
        }
```

I know that i must use await or delegates but i am stuck...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 8 async await usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090823/windows-phone-8-async-await-usage)

Comment: the example you suggest uses the GET method. I want the POST method, so i can pass a byte[] as a stream, as a parameter. Help anyone?

Comment: Use async/await. When it's done, the code will continue.

Comment: I tried. I can't async the Send Method. When i try the following line:
 await request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
i get a error: Cannot await 'System.IAsyncResult'

Comment: You need to call an `async` method to use `await`.

Comment: Finally made it. Exactly what i wanted found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098258/taskfactory-fromasync-with-begingetrequeststream-endgetrequeststream-hangs